# Convert Parameter from String to Number in Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can I convert a parameter of type string to number in Cloudformation ?

The situation is,

I want to define DedicatedMasterCount in AWS Elasticsearch resource and it needs a Number.

I define a parameter called DedicatedMasterCount with type Number. then refers to it

for example:

```
DedicatedMasterCount:
  Fn::If:
  - isDedicatedMasterEnabled
  - !Ref DedicatedMasterCount
  - AWS::NoValue
```

but !Ref converts Number directly to String automatically, which cause a error "Encountered non numeric value" resulting a failure by building stack

Comment: Why is `DedicatedMasterCount` referring to itself? Can you supply more code so we can test the situation ourselves? (eg a minimal template that demonstrates the problem?)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  thanks for the response. !Ref DedicatedMasterCount refers to a cloudformation parameter called DedicatedMasterCount

Comment: Well, that snippet is also called `DedicatedMasterCount`. Could that be causing a conflict?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  you are right. that was exactly the problem